# How to position <div> absolute to parent and relative to neighbors

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, position

I'm working on a simple little project right now and I can't seem to figure out the styling.

Basically, what I need to do is position a 'div' a certain number of pixels down from the top of its parent. To do this I made its position absolute and set top to whatever pixel offset I need. The problem with this is sometimes two 'div's will be at the same vertical position (or close to it) in the parent and will overlap. I need to have them line up side by side horizontally when they are overlapping. I know how to do this with a position of relative and the float property but this then breaks the vertical positioning.

The boxes are inserted dynamically with jQuery and their positions can change frequently.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ouyctuet/) to demonstrate.

HTML

```
<div class="main">
  This is okay
  <div style="top: 25px;" class="sub">
    <h3>
      test
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div style="top: 100px;" class="sub">
    <h3>
      test
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 200px;">
    This is the problem
  </div>
  <div style="top: 250px;" class="sub">
    <h3>
      test
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div style="top: 260px;" class="sub">
    <h3>
      test
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 700px;
}

.sub {
  border: thin solid black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may make the sub div's inside other div and give this one absolute position

```css
.main {
  position:relative;
  background-color: grey;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

.sub {
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  width:100%;
}
 .child {
  border:2px solid black;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  margin:10px auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="main">
   <div class="sub">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

if you want them horizontally add to **.child**

```
float:left;
width:47%;
margin:1%;
```

Comment: What I need is them to line up vertically unless they get placed in the same vertical position. Then the 2nd div should be placed on the right edge of the first div. There is the possibility of several being place at the same position vertically.

Comment: I didn't get the idea of what you need exactly. however you can use bootstrap and it will help you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell this isn't solvable with CSS. I ended up doing some decently complex javascript to detect collisions and reposition the div's appropriately.